# Updating appsettings.json values in azure deployed application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings, azure-application-settings

I've went through different answers before posting my question, but I need some assistance in order to resolve the issue.
This is sample of the appsettings I have deployed:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:mywebdb.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypass;"
  },
  "Clients": [
    {
      "ClientId": "spa",
      "ClientName": "SPA Client",
      "AllowedGrantTypes": [
        "authorization_code"
      ]
      "RedirectUris": [
        "http://localhost:4200/callback",
        "https://localhost:4200/callback",
        "http://localhost:4200",
        "https://localhost:4200",
        "http://localhost:4200/auth/login",
        "https://localhost:4200/auth/login",
        "https://google.com",
        "https://bing.com",
        "https://test.com",
        "https://nba.com"
      ],
      "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
        "http://localhost:4200/auth/login",
        "https://localhost:4200/auth/login"
      ],
      "AllowedCorsOrigins": [
        "http://localhost:4200",
        "https://localhost:4200"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to overwrite the values in the "RedirectUris" and "AllowedCorsOrigins" arrays, I tried something like this Clients:RedirectUris:8 in the application settings in azure but it doesn't work. Should I do something else or additional in order to have this working?

Answer (score 0):

Each configuration source (configuration provider) should be configured in the application itself:

See general guideline here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

**Azure App** configuration provider in particular, is described here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app

Answer (score 0):

Check the article: [Configure an ASP.NET Core app for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-dotnetcore?pivots=platform-windows):

> If you configure an app setting with the same name in App Service and
> in appsettings.json, for example, the App Service value takes
> precedence over the appsettings.json value. The local appsettings.json
> value lets you debug the app locally, but the App Service value lets
> your run the app in product with production settings. Connection
> strings work in the same way. This way, you can keep your application
> secrets outside of your code repository and access the appropriate
> values without changing your code.

Reference:

[Configure an App Service app in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common)

[ASP.NET Core AppSettings for Azure App Service](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/asp-net-core-appsettings-for-azure-app-service/ba-p/392596)